# Как обозначить куски кода для свертывания в AndroidStudio?

Tags: android-studio

Если код содержит класс, то его легко свернуть в одну строку, а потом развернуть (Ctrl + Shift + /).

А можно ли как-то на код внутри класса указать какими то скобками, что его тоже можно свернуть?

Comment: я так понимаю идет речь не о комментировании отдельного куска, а именно чтобы он сворачивался как и класс и как например метод?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно:

- выделить нужные строки.
- Меню "Code" - "Folding" - "Fold selection / Remove region" (или просто <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> на Windows и линуксе, <kbd>⌘</kbd>  + <kbd>.</kbd> на Mac)

*Приятная особенность: выделенный таким образом фрагмент остается отмеченным для сворачивания и после закрытия АС.*

Comment: Да, это то, что нужно! Спасибо!